# Get link clicked on menu

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I am using jQuery to fire a click event on a menu:

```
 <div id="context-menu">
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1">Color</a></li>
         <li><a tabindex="-1">Transparency</a></li>
         <li><a tabindex="-1">Show/Hide</a></li>
        <!-- <li class="divider"></li>
         <li><a tabindex="-1">Separated link</a></li>-->
      </ul>
    </div>
```

with this code:

```
$('#context-menu').on('click', function(e) {

console.log(e);

});
```

and I would understand how can I know which li is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a selector for the elements to match the click

```
$('#context-menu').on('click', '.dropdown-menu > li', function(e) {
```

now, in your handler, `this` refers to the clicked `li` element.

Answer (score 0):

The event parameter has a target property which is the actual element that was clicked(in this case either an `li` or an `a`), use it to get the li.

```
var li = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown-menu li')[0]
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `tabindex="-1"` deliberately? For keyboard accessibility, those `tabindex`es should be `tabindex="0"`, *not* `-1`. See http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex. It also looks like you should probably be using `<button>`s, not `<a>`s.

You should be adding a click handler to the `<a>`s like this:

```
$('#context-menu a').click(function() {
    // The <a> that was clicked.
    var theAnchorTag = $(this);
    // Its parent <li>.
    var theLiTag = theAnchorTag.parent();
});
```

Replace `a` with `button` in the selector above if you take my button advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(
  function(){
    console.log($(this).parent()); /* should return link's parent-node */
    console.log($(this).parent().index()); /* should return li's index */
  }
)
```